# Deserializing a complex JSON object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I use `JavaScript.Serializer.Deserializer` to deserialize a complex JSON object, as below:

```
{
    "name": "rule 1",
    "enabled": true,
    "conditions": [{
        "type": "time",
        "time": "17:23:10",
        "days": "125"
    }, {
        "type": "sensor",
        "uid": "10.2.0.1",
        "setpoint1": 12,
        "setpoint2": 18,
        "criterion": 1
    }, {
        "type": "sensor",
        "uid": "10.3.0.1",
        "setpoint1": 12,
        "setpoint2": 18,
        "criterion": 2
    }],
    "actions": {
        "period": 100,
        "single": false,
        "act": [{
            "type": "on",
            "uid": "10.1.0.1"
        }, {
            "type": "sms",
            "message": "Hello World"
        }]
    }
}
```

And I want to convert it to some classes, like below:

```
public class Rule
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
    public List<Condition> conditions { get; set; }
    public List<Action> actions { get; set; }
}

public class Condition
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? time { get; set; }
    public string days { get; set; }
    public double setpoint1 { get; set; }
    public double setpoint2 { get; set; }
    public int criterion { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public int period { get; set; }
    public bool single { get; set; }
    public List<Act> act { get; set; }
}

public class Act
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

The deserialization snippet:

```
json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Rule rule = (json.Deserialize<Rule>(jsonStr));
```

If I simplify the `Rule` class and declare `conditions` and `actions` as simple `strings`, it works fine.

But if I use the classes like above, it throws an exception:

> Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IoTWebApplication.Condition]'

Comment: Your JSON is not a valid JSON - please check with http://jsonlint.com and post the correct JSON

Comment: you're right, but I just indented that for better readability

Comment: Indentation is fine but it is still invalid - do you want to deserialize an invalid JSON -> that is not possible

Comment: The error message suggests that the JSON in your question is not what you're trying to deserialise. The only `List<Condition>` in your code is for `Rule.conditions`. The JSON in your question gives an array for that. The exception message *should* only ever appear if your real JSON doesn't use an array for that. Are you sure you've really got an array there?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, and when I use `public string conditions {get; set;};` instead of `public Condition[] conditions {get; set;};` or `public IEnumerable<Condition> conditions {get; set;};`, It works. and even when I deserialize that string again to a List of `Conditions` it works too. I think it means that the json is correct

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @Amir Yet when you've got an array, it shouldn't deserialise as a string, and doesn't (I just checked). It sounds like you've got a JSON-double-encoded array, something like `conditions:"[{...},{...},{...}]"` rather than the `conditions:[{...},{...},{...}]` you put in your question.

Comment: But I get the json from a web service

Comment: @Amir What's your point? If the web service gives you JSON-double-encoded data, yet if you changed that to JSON-regularly-encoded data before asking your question here, then of course the answers here aren't going to help you. If that's what happened, that isn't the web service's problem, that's your problem for asking a question where no answer can possibly help.

Comment: And we need to have the **real** data to give an answer to your **real** question. **fake** data will only result in answers to a **fake** question and will not answer your **real** question

Comment: I checked the data and it was (as you called it) double-encoded. But what I asked was that how I can change that when it comes from a web service?

Comment: @Amir That is a *new* question, so feel free to post another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the inner (nested) json was quoted and therefore was processed as a string. So when I removed the quotes, it worked fine:

```
json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Rule rule = (json.Deserialize<Rule>(jsonStr));
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure you create does not fit to the JSON you posted.

It should look like

```
public class Rule
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
    public Condition[ ] conditions { get; set; }
    public Actions actions { get; set; }
}

public class Actions
{
    public int period { get; set; }
    public bool single { get; set; }
    public Act[ ] act { get; set; }
}

public class Act
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class Condition
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string days { get; set; }
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public int setpoint1 { get; set; }
    public int setpoint2 { get; set; }
    public int criterion { get; set; }
}
```

It is (in most cases) very easy in VS to get the classes direct out of the JSON

- Copy JSON to clipboard
- In VS [EDIT/Special Paste/Paste JSON as Classes](http://blog.codeinside.eu/2014/09/08/Visual-Studio-2013-Paste-Special-JSON-And-Xml/) (the code above was created by this)

Comment: So you mean I have to use array, and not List?

I did that and still got exception

Comment: Pretty neat but `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` as well should work fine.

Comment: The above code is that what you get with Paste JSON as Classes

Comment: @Amir No, that is not the point but you have `Rule.actions` as `List<Action>` but that is wrong looking at your JSON

Comment: you're right, but I removed the entire action, and jsut focused on conditions, and it's still not working

Comment: Its valid now. Using your JSON and the class structure from Answer 1. It works.

Comment: @SirRufo When I use `public string conditions {get; set;};` instead of `public Condition[] conditions {get; set;};` or `public IEnumerable<Condition> conditions {get; set;};`, It works. and even when I deserialize that string again to a List of `Conditions` it works too.

Comment: @Amir I take **your** JSON and it is no problem to deserialize **your** JSON into **my** posted structure. So, what is the problem?

Comment: @Amir If that happens, then you did not post the **real** JSON you try to deserialize. How can we answer your **real** question when you ask us a **somehow lookalike** question?

Comment: @Amir Write the json (that one you try to deserialize) into a file and post the content of that file (no interpretation or edits or somehow lookalike) into the question, then we can help