# Having Trouble in Deserializing JSON with nested arrays in C#

Tags: c#, json, web-services, serialization

I'm having trouble trying to deserialize this JSON here:

```
{
  "CstCmpCode": "AH01",
  "Loaded_date": "13-Aug-2016",
  "Main_Group": "Neck Wraps",
  "sub_group": [
    {
      "Sub_Group": "AFGHANI",
      "ClosBal": 7
    },
    {
      "Sub_Group": "AFGHANI",
      "ClosBal": 13
    },
    {
      "Sub_Group": "AFGHANI",
      "ClosBal": -15
    }
  ]
}
```

The code or classes I created for this are :

```
public void TempStock(string CstCmpCode)
{
    try
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TallyWeb"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select CstCmpCode, Loaded_date, Main_Group, Sub_Group, ClosBal from TlyStkSumm where CstCmpCode = @CstCmpCode";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CstCmpCode", CstCmpCode);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row = null;
        foreach (DataRow rs in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, rs[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }

        this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        //this.Context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(rows));
        string json;
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows);
        //////JsonTest jobj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonTest>(json);
        ////var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonTest>>(json);
        //JavaScriptSerializer oJS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        //////testobject objtec = new testobject();
        ////objtec = oJS.Deserialize<testobject>(json);
        ////objtec = oJS.Deserialize<List<testobject>>(json);
        ////var s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        ////var t = s.Deserialize<List<JsonTest>>(json);
        //var jobj2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<JsonTest>>(json);
        //var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonTest>>(json);
        var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(json);
        //MyClass c = serializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(json);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        this.Context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(ex.Message));
    }
}

public class JsonTest
    {
        public string CstCmpCode { get; set; }
        public string Loaded_date { get; set; }
        public string Main_Group { get; set; }
        //public sub_group[] s;
        public List<sub_group> sub { get; set; }
    }
 public class sub_group
    {
        public string Sub_Group { get; set; }
        //public string ClosBal { get; set; }
    }
```

Pls. tell me where I am going to wrong

Comment: You can build the class structure direct from the JSON. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/38161247/1744164

Comment: Your current code is not compiling. Where is MyClass defined? Please put more effort in your question regarding content and formatting.

Comment: @SirRufo Pls. check TempStock(string CstCmpCode) Mehtod

Comment: @SirRufo pls. help me it is very necessary for me

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i am going totally in wrong way first i have to just convert my DataTable to nested json string then after i have to Deserialize them.

Comment: If it were so necessary you would have edited your question to show us a compilable code.

Answer (score 0):

Download Newtonsoft.Json nuget package to your project and use this code

This is your model

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string CstCmpCode { get; set; }
    public string Loaded_date { get; set; }
    public string Main_Group { get; set; }
    public Result[] results { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string Sub_Group { get; set; }
    public int ClosBal { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize your string like this

```
var myObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json)
```

Comment: @YogeshSharma then do the rest  :) your model format was wrong and I didn't see a line that you used JsonConvert

Comment: In my model problem or in my web services ??

Comment: @YogeshSharma First in your model you have a list of sub, but in your json it is called results.

Comment: Then you have json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows); for serializing but new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize.. to deserialize. what is going on?

Comment: @YogeshSharma replace your models with mine and test again. then come back

Comment: Now, this is the my first class  public class JsonTest
    {
        public string CstCmpCode { get; set; }
        public string Loaded_date { get; set; }
        public string Main_Group { get; set; }
        //public sub_group[] s;
        public List<sub_group> sub { get; set; }
    }

Comment: and this is the second  public class sub_group
    {
        public string Sub_Group { get; set; }
        public string ClosBal { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Dude! copy my model! is it that hard?! List<sub_group> sub { get; set; } is not in your json

Comment: None of JSON Response showing (i.e. showing blank) and deserializ string like :  var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(json);

Comment: pls. tell where i am going wrong ?? i am new in Web API

Comment: @AshkanSirous Your model is also wrong. I can not see any *result* property inside JSON, but a property *sub_group* which is not in your model

Comment: @YogeshSharma. ok, lets check the basics. are you sure that your service is been called? to make sure, put a breakpoint on the first line of your method and then call it, then tell me what happend

Comment: I have put the breakpoints in MyClass but, it is not getting hitting

Comment: @YogeshSharma how do you call your service?

Comment: @YogeshSharma you need to call it somehow. try this tutorial first. It is very easy to follow http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: @YogeshSharma I guess you are starting to work with web. See, when you have a web application you need a client to call it. if it is a page, or HTTP Get you can use a browser. when you call your address, your method will be hit and we can follow to see your problem

Comment: i am just calling same as method

Comment: @YogeshSharma, ok, edit your question and put your controllers code and a picture of how are you calling it  bellow your current qustion

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api this link contains MVC Code but im designing the web api using web services have you checked live ? so, i can send the link of web api and what response it is shwoing..

Comment: @AshkanSirous pls. help me it is very necessary for me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i am going totally in wrong way first i have to just convert my DataTable to nested json string then after i have to Deserialize them